# How do I format the output from regular expression matches into a simple list that I can use to select rows in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I tried to convert the actual matches `[F.....]` to list or list of strings but did not convert in the right format:

```
    regex = re.compile(r'(^A[0-9]....|^B[0-9]....|^C[0-9]....|^carp_P[0- 
    9]....|^F[0-9]....|^H[0-9]....|^O[0-9]....|^Q[0-9]....)')
    regex.split(text)
    matches = re.findall(regex, text)
```

If matches:

```
                match_lst = []
                match_lst.append(matches)
                print(match_lst)
                match_str = ''.join(str(e) for e in match_lst)
                print(match_str)
```

If I create my own simple list then my code works for accession numbers when I set that column as the index [`F6XW64`, etc. as the index) then it works.

```
rows = ['F6XW64', 'F6XRH6']
filename = 'Select_Columns_Macho.xlsx'
df2 = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=0, header = 0)
df2.set_index('Accession', inplace = True)
df3 = df2.loc[rows]
print (df3)
```

These lists and string generated from my regular expressions search above does not work in my code below. It seems like a format issue, but I have not been able to figure it out.

I hope to pull our rows in a pandas data frame that contain a list of index labels, but the list generated from regular expressions and my efforts to format the output from regular expression into a simple list like rows above is not working.

Comment: what does `print(match_lst)` print??

Comment: it prints the matches within two sets of brackets

Comment: Thanks for commenting. It prints the matches within two sets of brackets [[F6A345]] [[A6W345]] etc.